# Why isn't the listener set properly in this case

Tags: android, events, view, android-framelayout

In my activity, I display a camera preview and a button (a `view` that looks like a button) that I draw over it. The problem is that when I set the click listener on that View, no matter where I click on the screen (even on the camera preview) the click event is fired.

This is the code :

```
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

    CameraButtonView cameraButton = new CameraButtonView(getBaseContext());
    preview.addView(cameraButton);

    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CameraTestActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

So the `FrameLayout` is the Camera Preview. The `CameraButtonView` is the view that gets drawn on it (somewhere at the bottom .. it doesn't take much space) and the listener is really set on the view.

Why is it that when I click anywhere on the `FrameLayout` my event gets triggered ? Also, how could I fix it so that only the button is subscribed to the event.

---

Camera Button View :

```
public class CameraButtonView extends View
{
Paint buttonPaint = new Paint();
Paint textPaint = new Paint();

SizeF size = new SizeF(500, 125);

public CameraButtonView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    buttonPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(35);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    RectF surface = RectangleHelper.create(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    PointF alignedPoint = RectangleHelper.align(surface, size, ContentAlignment.BottomCenter, AlignmentType.Internal);
    RectF content = RectangleHelper.create(alignedPoint, size);
    Rect textRectangle = new Rect();
    String buttonText = "Click to take a pic.";

    buttonPaint.getTextBounds(buttonText, 1, buttonText.length(), textRectangle);

    PointF alignedTextPoint = RectangleHelper.align(content, new SizeF(textRectangle.width(), textRectangle.height()), ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, AlignmentType.Internal);

    canvas.drawRect(content, buttonPaint);
    canvas.drawText(buttonText, alignedTextPoint.x, alignedTextPoint.y, textPaint);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the layoutparams on the CameraButtonView are larger than what the button actually looks like.  Try to set the layoutparms to new LayoutParams(50,50) and see if it helps. Then you'll need to workout how to size it relatively.

Without seeing the code for CameraButtonView, I can't give a definitive answer.

UPDATE (working):

```
CameraButtonView cameraButton = new CameraButtonView(getBaseContext());
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(500, 125);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;
    cameraButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    preview.addView(cameraButton);
```

Comment: Or, override onDraw of CameraButtonView and do canvas.drawColor(Color.Magenta);.  Then see if it is filling the entire screen.

Comment: No, it's not the same color it's already RED and I can clearly see that it only takes some part of the screen at the bottom.

Comment: CameraButtonView cameraButton = new CameraButtonView(getBaseContext());
  cameraButton.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(500, 125));
  preview.addView(cameraButton);

Comment: This works partially. It will work but will move my button on the top right corner. When it should be in the bottom center.

Comment: Can you use an ImageButton and hide the backgound?  Then, simply setImageBitmap(custombitmap) if you want a dynamic image?

Comment: No unfortunatelly using that control isn't a solution.

Comment: Or/Also, try to put this in an xml layout with typical view attributes.  It may solve a lot of problems here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45851/discussion-between-beplaya-and-phadaphunk)